# Chrome "immersive-vr" isSessionSupported gives false with threejs.org examples

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, virtual-reality, steamvr, webxr

currently it looks to me like Chrome 83, does not support any VR experience although HTC Vive is connected (SteamVR 1.9.16 installed). SteamVR, when started manually, also finds the headset, controllers and base station.

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=webxr#webxr_vr_ballshooter

Any VR Example states "VR not supported"

digging arround a bit, the navigator describes the "immersive-vr" session not to be available. Promise response of code below is: false

```
navigator.xr.isSessionSupported('immersive-vr').then((issupported) => {console.log(issupported)})
```

The previous flags of Chrome (83.0.4103.61) linked to WebXR are not available any more.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

```
navigator.xr.requestSession( 'immersive-vr', { optionalFeatures: [ 'local-floor', 'bounded-floor' ] } ).then( (session) => console.log(session) );
```

Gives:
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The specified session configuration is not supported.

Comment: Filled a bug Report
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1088046&q=isSessionSupported&can=2

Comment: Exact same problem with me except I have an Oculus Rift.  This is a constant problem with the browsers (at least with WebVR), they go in and out of support.  I would always have to switch between chrome, ff, and ff-nightly.  Firefox nightly currently shows isSessionSupported('immersive-xr') true, but it doesn't consider the click to be 'interactive', hence you cannot use it as a workaround (ff-nightly appears to be getting close to implementing XR, but still not there).  Thanks for filing the chrome bug report.

Comment: Actually in search for a quite stable solution, I am using the slimjet browser, which is currently based on chrome 81 and the updates being stalled, to avoid surprises during development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue will be solved by SteamVR supporting OpenVR as they are going to...

https://steamcommunity.com/games/250820/announcements/detail/2396425843528787270

Until then I would recommend to use:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --enable-features=openvr --disable-features=XRSandbox --force-webxr-runtime=openvr --enable-experimental-web-platform-features https://threejs.org/
```

Comment: In this time, these switches are deleted